# NHibernate Select N+1 with HasOne Mapping

Tags: sql-server, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, iqueryable

I have two tables modeled by the following entities:

```
public class Product : ModifiableEntity
{
    public virtual int ProductId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductStats Stats { get; set; }
}

public class ProductStats : ModifiableEntity
{
    public virtual int ProductStatId { get; set; }

    public virtual int? QtyAvail { get; set; }7

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

With the following fluent mappings:

```
public class ProductMap : ModifiableEntityClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Table("Product");
        Id(x => x.ProductId).Column("ProductId").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x =>     x.Description).Column("Description").Nullable().Length(Int32.MaxValue);

        HasOne(x => x.Stats)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Product)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}


public class ProductStatsMap : ModifiableEntityClassMap<ProductStats>
{
    public ProductStatsMap()
    {
        Table("ProductStats");
        Id(x => x.ProductStatId).Column("ProductStatId").GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.QtyAvail).Column("QtyAvail").Nullable();

        References(x => x.Product).Column("ProductId")
                                  .Unique()
                                  .Cascade.All()
                                  .Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

I have 7005 products in my test database and the inner join between products and products stats is 1 to 1 and returns 7005 records, yet when I run the following query, I see almost 30,0000 queries in SQL profiler.

```
 var products = from p in _productRepository.Linq()
                select p;
```

I have tried every variation of:

```
        HasOne(x => x.Stats)
            .Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Join()
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Product)
            .Cascade.All();
```

As well as specifying fetch on the linq query but no matter what I try, the result is tens of thousands of queries being run against my SQL server.

Any help that anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you need to eager load the **ProductStats**. You may achieve this by two ways:

1. By adding **.Not.LazyLoad()** when mapping the Stats property, as follows:

   ```
   HasOne(x => x.Stats)
       .PropertyRef(x => x.Product)
       .Not.LazyLoad()
       .Cascade.All();
   ```

or

2. By using the namespace **NHibernate.Linq**, as follows:

   ```
   session.Query<Product>().Fetch(p => p.Stats).ToFuture();
   ```

   This will make NHibernate execute only two queries in only one database round trip. The first query will get the products, and the second will get every productStats that was fetched in the first one.

The only issue with the first approach is that it will affect every single query that you execute. By the other hand, you can use the second approach only when you really need it.

Nevertheless, there is still something bugging me: do you really need the "Product" property in the stats? Because you could have some problems with circular reference.